# Good HTML/Javascript Poll Widgets

Tags: javascript, html, widget

Facebook and Twitter have some cool widgets (share, comments, etc.) but I can not find similar poll widgets.

What simple, customizable, and free poll widgets are there?

Answer (score 1):

In pure Javascript and HTML, you will be hard-pressed to find a solution for what you are looking for. You need a way to save the data from polls somehow, so you will need a server-side languange and some sort of database. If you were just asking about the poll, I always suggest using jQuery plugins, so take a look at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jPoll